# ROCKSDB Failed to acquire lock due to rocksdb_max_row_locks

Tags: python, mariadb, rocksdb

I'm trying to load a CSV in to my  rocksdb database, but it fails and show me this error:

`Got error 10 'Operation aborted:Failed to acquire lock due to rocksdb_max_row_locks limit' from ROCKSDB`

I've tried with `SET SESSION rocksdb_max_row_locks=1073741824;` but same error always.

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick (before starting the insert)

> SET session rocksdb_bulk_load=1;